# passing an array as an index to another array?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, image-processing

alright so I'm writing some code used for image processing and most of it is converted from some old matlab code for the same process. At the point I'm at now(the final step in the process) I need to pass an array as an index to another array.

a bit of background: I'm separating the images in to RGB bands or mask. earlier in the code I took all the images(as numpy arrays) and took a median along along the 3rd dimension. I'm trying to pass the RGB mask as arguments so I can get the median along those pixel values, and have 0's in place of the RB pixels.

The code in Matlab to do this is pretty straightforward:

```
finalMedGreen_ROI(exp_i+1) = median(median(EXPMedian_ROI(GMask_ROI)));
```

where GMask_ROI is an array that is a region of interest of the raw image data, and EXPMedian_ROI is the Median of all the raw image data).

I tried to replicate this in python:

```
self.final_median_green_roi[image+1] = np.median(np.median(self.exposure_median_roi(self.green_mask_roi)))
```

and I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I tried to simply pass both arrays as arguments in np.median. here's the thing, self.green_mask_roi is an array of boolean values(true for green pixels, false for everything else. when I ran this:

```
self.final_median_green_roi[0,1] = np.median(np.median(self.dark_median_roi,self.green_mask_roi))
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I'm not sure if it's suggesting those for the boolean array or the numeric median array and I'd rather get it right simply for the fact that I'm new to image processing and I'm unlikely to catch the mistake. any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve with the placement of dark_median_roi and green_mask_roi. You can't do what they did in the example because they are both arrays. In the example, EXPMedianROI was a method being called on GMask_ROI

Comment: the arrays are raw image data (images in terms of RGGB values). what I'm attempting to do is gather the median values for every pixel that is green. the median is then passed to more times to compress it down to a singular value.

Comment: So do you want to find the median of the combined two arrays? (Union or intersection?)

Comment: well like I said one of those arrays is filled with boolean values, so I guess a better way of putting it is I want to turn off every value in the first array that is false in the second array.

Comment: The `callable` error means that you using a `arr(idx)` syntax on an array, instead of the proper indexing one, `arr[idx]`.  Remember indexing syntax is different in `numpy`.  Either that of you are using an array in a place where you should be using a function.

Comment: The `ambiguous` error means that you are using a True/False array in a context that expects a scalar boolean, such as a simple `if` statement.  In numpy, `arr>0` produces are boolean array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy's builtin mask arrays:

```
...  =np.median(np.median(np.ma.masked_array(self.dark_median_roi‌​, self.green_mask_roi)))
```

This creates a new array by making a mask of the 2nd parameter, self.green_mask_roi, and applying it to the 1st, self.dark_median_roi, so that you get an array that has all of the original elements of self.dark_median_roi that are also present in self.green_mask_roi.

Comment: the first time I ran this it said it was an invalid operation for an int and generator expression. so I put this inside an np.array statement and but some brackets around it and I got this error again: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Try this: `=np.median(np.median(np.ma.masked_array(self.dark_median_roi, self.green_mask_roi)))`

Comment: Also, what are the dimensions of those two arrays? I've been assuming they are 1-dimensional

Comment: Great to hear! I'll edit the answer and if you could mark as accepted answer that would be awesome.

Comment: they are both shaped (200,200)